# Autoindent unordered lists that start with a hyphen in cpp files

Tags: formatting, comments, filetype-c++

## The context

I've the following options in my `vimrc`

```
set formatoptions=cnroqj
set textwidth=80
```

When editing `tex` files, lines whose content is longer than `&textwidth` is
splitted and formatted as it follows

```
% - foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
%   foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
%
% 1. bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
%    bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
```

When editing `cpp` files, lines whose content is longer than `&textwidth` is
splitted and formatted as it follows

```
// - foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
// foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
//
// 1. bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
//    bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
```

As you can see, in files whose filetype is `cpp`, lists present in comments
lines that start with the `-` character are not formatted when reaching the
value of `&textwidth` just as happens with files whsoe filetype is `tex`.

## The question

How can I make lists from comment lines that start with the `-` character to be
automatically indented in files whose filetype is `cpp`?

## Additional context

1. I've noticed that the `/usr/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin/c.vim` file sets the value
   of the `formatoptions` option for `cpp` files. However, even when I set the same value for the
   `&formatoptions` option in both buffers (`tex` and `cpp`) I got the same
   behavior.
2. Some people recommend [modifying the `comments` option](https://superuser.com/questions/131950/indentation-for-plain-text-bulleted-lists-in-vim), [modifying the `formatlistpat` option](https://blog.siddharthkannan.in/vim/configuration/2019/11/02/format-list-pat-and-vim/) (also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/99138/bulleted-lists-for-plain-text-documents-in-vim)), [setting the `autoindent` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282355/how-to-get-vim-to-format-bulleted-lists-with-correct-indentation) but I'm not sure which one I must modify for this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `after/ftplugin/c.vim` or `after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
let &l:formatlistpat .= '\|^\s*-\s*'
```

It tell vim to recognize `-` as numbered list.

set them in `vimrc` is a mistake, this option is local to buffer. You can use `:verbose setlocal formatlistpat` to check if it's set properly.

Result:

```
// - foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
//   foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
//
// 1. bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
//    bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
```

when you execute `gqip`, vim first format them as comments(see `:h format-comments` if you are interested), then it formats then as numbered list, I guess the `//` is ignored durring pattern match for `:h formatlistpat`

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this behavior with this minimalist `vimrc`

```
set nocompatible
filetype on

set textwidth=80
set formatoptions=c

let g:tex_flavor="latex" 

au Filetype tex set comments=sO:%\ -,mO:%\ \ ,:%
au Filetype cpp set comments=sO:\/\/\ -,mO:\/\/\ \ ,:\/\/
```

When editing `tex` files you would get the following

```
% - foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
%   foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

When editing `cpp` files you would get the following

```
// - foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
//   foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```